# How can we make daemon application?

Tags: android, daemon

Have a native android app running like a daemon.
In my application which we are developing. How can we make an application which one is working on background while we are opening another things?

Comment: Ideally a daemon is supposed to be outside of the scope of an application.

Comment: Could you explain it with a code sample please?

Comment: "How can we make an application which one is working on background while we are opening another things?" - I think, Android Service is the right component for your need.

Answer (score -2):

I have some idea about it. It can be make your process undead. It works well from api 8 to 23. No matter "force close" in Settings or "background clean" in third-party app with root.

see https://github.com/Marswin/MarsDaemon